# No sound through handset speaker of Nexus S

Tags: audio, samsung-nexus-s

Suddenly when I was playing music on my Nexus S it stopped playing all sounds through the handset speaker. It still works though if I use an external headset though.

I don't really have that much knowledge of the Android internal workings to see what the problem is, although I tried rebooting it.

I also can't really leave it for warranty repair because the boot-loader is unlocked (although I later reflashed back to the stock ROM).

Comment: You can re-lock the bootloader easily (if no severe hw problem exists that prevents it): boot into fastboot mode and issue a `fastboot oem lock` command.

Answer (score 1):

I just saw this googling around, maybe it could be of help to you:

> okay, I had the exact same problem. My speaker suddenly stopped
>   working even though the ear phone plugin was still working good. I
>   also found that sometime the sound came back but it is very weak,
>   barely audible. and then it would disappear again. What I did to fix
>   the problem is to open up the N1, disassemble instruction is on
>   youtube. Open the the 3 screws to remove the board with the attached
>   speaker from the main board. clean up the speaker attachment surface
>   really good. Then reassemble the backboard and its speaker together.
>   Then the sound came back loud and strong.
>
> My guess is that the contact of the speaker could get dirty and
>   limit the electric supply to the speaker hence it didn't work
>   properly. By cleaning the surface I helped to get the current going
>   again and the sound came back. Hope that this could help someone since
>   this problem had driven me insane for a while.

I found this on the following website: http://www.nexusoneforum.net/forum/nexus-s-general-discussion/12468-external-speaker-not-working.html.

Cheers, and I hope this helps.

Comment: That one says N1, Nexus One.

Comment: Since the original question was for the Nexus S and the Forum is a joint Nexus 1/ Nexus S forum, I was hoping it would be helpful.

Comment: as I said, yes, that makes sense, although the instructions are for the Nexus 1.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the backside speakers? Suddenly mine wasn't working too (the front one still did though) and I just rebooted my phone :P And it worked again. Maybe you should try that. :)

Comment: Yes, I am talking about the backside speakers. Yes, I have tried rebooting. No, it didn't work. However, it's been on repair now and works like a charm again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with my wife's Galaxy Nexus.

No sound through the built-in speaker in regular call mode. The other party could hear her, so the Microphone was OK. The speaker worked in loudspeaker mode, but not regular.  Headphones also worked properly.

What fixed it was removing the battery and leaving it off for 5 minutes before re-installing and rebooting. I'd tried numerous reboots previously and they didn't help, nor did a quick battery removal and replacement.

Comment: While it might have been unclear from the question, my problem was actually the opposite (loudspeaker broken, regular worked), but interesting info.